# Neural network doesn't return values below 0.5 with logsig

Tags: matlab, neural-network, pattern-recognition

I want to classify two classes with a neural network. Since outputs are 0 or 1, I am using (or trying t use) 'logsig' for the output function.
My problem is that when I do that, my simulations end up being between 0.5 and 1. As if everything entering the logsig function was positive.

PS: My training set and my testing set are composed of normalized values.

Here is what I do:

```
t = [0.8*ones(1,50) 0.2*ones(1,50)];
%define net
net = newff(trainSet,t,n,{'tansig','logsig'},'trainscg');
net.trainparam.epochs = 100;
net.trainParam.goal = 0;
%train net
net = train(net,trainSet,t);
%test net
%%on testing set
outputs = sim(net,testSet)
```

Comment: How have you normalised? Especially what do your output variables in your training set look like?

Comment: I have changed them so that mean would be 0 and variance 1. Here is a sample: 0.583655523269032 -0.570741924698547
0.445428970212546 -0.480186786378411
0.384208559039074 -0.624453529130333

Comment: But `logsig` can only produce outputs between 0 and 1, so surely then you should have normalized (at least your outputs) to be between zero and one instead of trying to standardize them as you have. How can `logsig` possibly produce a result like `-0.624453529130333`?

Comment: Only the inputs have been normalized. The output targets are "t = [0.8*ones(1,50) 0.2*ones(1,50)];"
My issue is that it doesn't produce results like 0.2

Comment: (with 'tansig', it producces them but it's not satisfying since i do not use the advantages of the function (its shape))

Comment: Is your `t` completely synthetic? Is there any basic for the first half of the training set to result in one class and the second in another (lower valued) class? Are you aiming for regression or classification (i.e. why didn't you use 1 and 0 instead of 0.8 and 0.2)? Are you sure that any of the records in your test set *should* be producing outputs of 0.2?

Comment: I could go for 0 and 1. The 0.2 and 0.8 helps avoiding that large values are not sent to the tail of the function. But I did try with 0 and 1 and the problem remains.

Comment: A pureline on the input allows for scaling issues on inputs.  It can have similar function on outputs.  Logsig and purelin are the components used for the "universal function approximator".  Why did you choose your epochs and training algorithm?  Consider this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65877/convergence-of-neural-network-weights/65891#65891