# Matlab Neural Net: tansig always returns positive value

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

I am undertaking a classification task, but face the problem that when I run my patterns over the trained net, I only get a +ve classification (equiv to [logsig always > 0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216608/neural-network-doesnt-return-values-below-0-5-with-logsig)), whereas I expect tansig should be returning -ve values frequently when I apply the trained net to the original patterns (last line of code below).

All the normalization is taking place automatically by the builtin functions, and the results are shown below.

[image: summary of my results]

Advice?

```
[patterns,targets] = getData();
patterns = patterns';  % 11x3078
targets = targets';    %  1x3078

learner = 'trainlm'; % 'trainlm', 'trainbr', 'trainscg'
hiddenSizes = 5;  % default is 10
net = feedforwardnet(hiddenSizes, learner);

% inps = net.inputs{1}.processFcns;
% default for hidden layers is 'tansig'
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig';
% default for hidden layers is 'purelin'
% tansig is preferred over a linear function for classification
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'tansig';

net.divideParam.trainRatio = 0.7;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 1 - net.divideParam.trainRatio;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 0.0;

[net, tr] = train(net, patterns, targets);   % train the networks

%% Test the Network
outputs = net(patterns);
```

Comment: What is the ratio of positive patterns to negative patterns?

Comment: I've added a confusion matrix

Comment: Well, since some samples of class 0 are correctly classified,  `tansig` must have been returning some negative values, right? Though I am assuming your algorithm rounds -ve values to class 0 and +ve values to class 1.